# Role of namespace while working with globalization & localization in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an `AccountController`:

```
namespace SampleWebApp.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer<AccountController> _localizer;

        public AccountController(IStringLocalizer<AccountController> localizer)
        {
            _localizer = localizer;
        }

        // GET: Account
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string InvalidUserString = _localizer["InvalidUser"];
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I added required code for globalization & localization as per instructions given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [here](https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-localization-deep-dive)

My resources folder structure is:

[image: Resource Folder Structure]

If I keep the following properties for my project, then I can get value in  `string InvalidUserString`:

1. Assembly name = SampleWebApp
2. Default namespace = SampleWebApp
3. Namespace at code level = SampleWebApp

**Questions**:

1. If I set empty value for assembly name, then why I can not get value in  `string InvalidUserString`
2. If I set different value for "2. Default namespace" & "3. Namespace at code level" then why I can not get value in  `string InvalidUserString`

Is there any solution for the above?